# No Database Selected Php

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache

This is a somewhat simple task, I am trying to compare a username to that in the database. I am testing it out in a single php file before I do it properly. My code is below. Basically I have a user, which is in the database and I am checking if it is in there.

```
<?php
$db_connect = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "anwesha01", "mis");
//Check if connection worked.
if(!$db_connect) 
{
    die("Unable to connect to database: " . mysql_error()); 
}
//For testing purposes only.
else 
{
    echo "Database connect success!";   
}

$user = "alj001";
$query = "SELECT Username FROM `user` WHERE `Username` = '".$user."'";

//What is being passed through the database.
echo "<p><b>This is what is being queried:</b> " . $query;  

//Result
if (mysql_query($query, $db_connect))
{
    echo "<br> Query worked!";  
}
else
{
    echo "<p><b>MySQL error: </b><br>". mysql_error();  
}   
 ?>
```

**The result I get is:**

> Database connect success!
>   **This is what is being queried:** SELECT Username FROM `user` WHERE `Username` = 'alj001'
>
> **MySQL error:**  No database selected

First I had my mysql_query without the $db_connect as it is above, but I put it in and I still get "no database selected".

Ive looked at the w3c schools for the mysql_query function, I believe I have done everything correctly. http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_query.asp

Comment: You need `mysql_select_db`. But in actuality, you should be using `mysqli`.

Comment: And this is why you should never use w3schools. Teaching people to use `mysql_*` functions borders on criminal irresponsibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you haven't called `mysql_select_db`. Note that [the 4th parameter to `mysql_connect` is not what you think it is](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

That said, [you really should be using `PDO` or `mysqli`, not the plain `mysql_` functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php), since they're deprecated.